# Material Design Menus

Tags: css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm dabbling with the material design concepts (currently using googles MDL) to build a application, realistically only used on desktops.  I am wondering what the appropriate approach to having a persistent tool bar along the bottom of the screen is.  This tool bar is not full length, and will be context sensitive so will actually change in length depending on what is selected.   Really i am wondering the best container and best method to position it whilst sticking (roughly!) to the MD guidelines...

previously i would have styled it into position using..

```
#toolbar{
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

which is fine, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach in general or breaking the guidelines of MD

Should I instead put it into a grid (say a 3-6-3 col)? or maybe use a card?

Please bare in mind that there will be things going on behind the toolbars, e.g. full screen pictures/webGL models which I want the tool bars to sit on top of

I have attached a picture, the pink represents the toolbar with its icons. the grey background will potentially have some webgl and images.  There will be other toolbars around also, but this will be the main used one.[image]

i hope this makes sense, i can potentially mock up something in code, but if someone could give me a rough idea of the approach i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to a sticky footer would be to use CSS `calc` function. I would also suggest changing your toolbar to a flexbox as it is arguably the most dynamic container for which children items change.

```
#toolbar {
    display: flex;
    min-height: clac(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply much appriciated.How would that position it at the bottom of the screen and centred though?  would i use in it conjunction with my original code mentioned in the question?am i missing something obvious? Oh and for other peoples benefit if they just try to copy and past, you spelt calc wrong.  Thanks

Comment: It should replace your original code.

CSS tricks has a great guide to flexbox that will help you understand the properties of felxbox better.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If you want the flexbox centered on the page use the `justify-content: center;` attribute value.